# Does sequelize 7.0.0-alpha.4 prevent sql injection with mysql raw query?

Tags: node.js, security, sequelize.js, sql-injection, raw-query-builder

I am using below code for update but i need to prevent sql injection in this query.

```
const query1 = `UPDATE Table SET name='xyz' WHERE id=1`;
const saveEditPost = await sequelizeWrite.query(query1, { type: sequelizeWrite.QueryTypes.UPDATE });
```

How to prevent sql injection in the code using sequelize? i have used sequelize in my entire projects to change the package will be a challenge.

Comment: What the difference between Sequelize 7.x and previous versions in this aspect? You still can use `bind` or `replacements` options to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Anatoly make sure you update to the latest version because there was recently SQL injection on `replacements` https://www.redpacketsecurity.com/node-js-sequelize-module-sql-injection/

Comment: @prospector the link says it would be sufficient to install 6.19.1 or later.